# How to take values from a column and assign them to other columns

Tags: sql, sql-server

Here's what I have:

```
DECLARE @keyString2 nvarchar(500)
SET @keyString2 = 
    (SELECT TOP (1) Key_analysis 
    FROM  testing.dbo.[nameWIthoutSpecialChars])
IF CHARINDEX('Limit of Insurance Relativity Factors' , @keyString2) > 0
   EXEC sp_rename 'testing.dbo.nameWIthoutSpecialChars.Key2', 
                  'Limit of Insurance Relativity Factors', 
                  'COLUMN';
```

Basically what I'm doing with that code is renaming column names
with values that are from a different column. Though, if you see, there's a hardcoded string in CHARINDEX, I'd have to already know what's inside of that variable which makes it a real manual process. I could essentially just hardcode the EXEC and run it over and over without even needing the IF statement.

What I'm trying to accomplish is to rename columns based off of values inside of another.

To make it more clear I have a table like this:

```
+--------------------------------+---------+---------+
| Description                    | Column2 | Column3 |
+--------------------------------+---------+---------+
| string value 1, string value2  |         |         |
+--------------------------------+---------+---------+
| string value 1, string value2  |         |         |
+--------------------------------+---------+---------+
| string value 1, string value 2 |         |         |
+--------------------------------+---------+---------+
```

The values in the "Description" column will be the same throughout the table. What I want to have happen is that those values replace the other columns like so

```
+--------------------------------+----------------+----------------+
| Description                    | string value 1 | string value 2 |
+--------------------------------+----------------+----------------+
| string value 1, string value2  |                |                |
+--------------------------------+----------------+----------------+
| string value 1, string value2  |                |                |
+--------------------------------+----------------+----------------+
| string value 1, string value 2 |                |                |
+--------------------------------+----------------+----------------+
```

The only other caveat here is that there may be more or less string values than the 2 shown, I want to run this through multiple tables. Every table has 10 columns that are just like "Column1" and "Column2" in the example, meaning 10 potential columns that need to be renamed considering how many values are in the "Description" column

Comment: update myTbl set col3 = col2 where somecol = 'someval'

Answer (score 0):

Experimental table,I didn't use #temporary table or table variable.

```
create TABLE bbbb  (
   Description VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL 
  ,column2     VARCHAR(30)
  ,column3     VARCHAR(30)
);
INSERT INTO bbbb(Description,column2,column3) VALUES 
('string value 1,string value2',NULL,NULL),
('string value 1,string value2',NULL,NULL),
('string value 1,string value2',NULL,NULL);
```

final query

```
declare @a varchar(100);
declare @b varchar(100);
set @a=(select distinct PARSENAME(REPLACE(Description,',','.'),1) from bbbb)
set @b=(select distinct PARSENAME(REPLACE(Description,',','.'),2) from bbbb)
EXEC sp_rename '[bbbb].[column2]', @a, 'COLUMN'; 
EXEC sp_rename '[bbbb].[column3]', @b, 'COLUMN'; 

select  * from bbbb
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Do you know how I'd get this to work with 3 or more columns? I tried adding another variable, set, and exec statement and I can't seem to get it to work. Like say I had another column in the bbbb table called column4, and another string value in the description column